# proxy with relative URLs

Tags: html, proxy, web, response

I'm trying to create a proxy web page that retrieves content from another website.

The html content loads, but javascript/css/images using relative urls are not found as they are pointing to the local server.

Without parsing the content and re-writing urls (especially since some of the urls are generated via javascript), is there a way to specify the base url via response.headers (like in the html head) to trick the browser so that the page can continue to function?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Content-Base response header, such as

```
Content-base: http://google.com/
```